# How can I line up my bullet images with my <li> content?

Tags: html, css

Heres a screenshot to make it clear. I'm trying to figure out a robust way of making the bullet images vertically aligned to my li content. As you can see my content is currently too high.

Many thanks 'over-flowers'...

http://dl.getdropbox.com/u/240752/list-example.gif

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, some css code to see how you currently set your bullet images would be useful ;-)

Instead of actually setting the 'list-style-image' property, I've had far more consistent results with setting a background-image property for the li element. You can then control the positioning with pixel accuracy. Remember to set a suitable left-padding value to push your list item contents clear of the bullet image.

Comment: i currenty use the method that Galwegian has shown. I'll give your '<li> with background image' method a whirl. Looks like I'll have more flexibilty lining up the image :)

Comment: I've never even used "list-style-image" because back when I started using CSS it was discouraged (Netscape 4) didn't support it properly. Even now that all browsers support it, I find the "background-image" approach far more useful.

Answer (score 3):

I like @bryn's answer. 
One example I've used successfully:

```
#content ul li {
    margin: 3px -20px 3px 20px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
    list-style: none;
    background: url(newbullet.gif) no-repeat 0 3px;
}
```

The negative right margin may or may not be needed in your case. 
You may need to adjust to meet your specific needs depending on your image. (My image is 14 x 15.)
You **must** specifically set margins **and** padding if you want a similar look across browsers as Firefox and IE use different defaults for displaying bullets.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this in your css...

```
#content li{

    list-style-image: url(../images/bullet.gif);

}
```

Comment: thanks dude, that what I use already, ( should have posted CSS!). Bryn's method will hopefully allow me to tinker with the alignment  a little more.

Answer (score 2):

use background-image, for your li elements, add padding.

```
.box li{
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-image: url("img/list_icon.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 2px;
    margin-top: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Pixel background positions are prone to produce problems. Instead, use relative qualifiers `center left`. Addionally, do you know the `background` property shortcut?

Comment: yes i do know the shortcut, but i like my declarations verbose. pixel positioning addresses the very problem Pickledegg described - images are not nicely aligned vertically by default and design of the bullets may require pixel-level adjusting.